# Positioning an image with a JSP Bean Variable

Tags: html, jsp, position, javabeans

I am creating a html web page using JSP / JSF integrated with a MySQL database.

I want to put an image on a specific position, according to a value from a Bean; so I am trying to do as the code below:

```
<h: img src="icon.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:'.#{page_bean.dbtable_variable}.'px;"/>
```

Trying this, I get this error:

> '#{} not allowed in a template text body.'

Any idea of how can I fix this or a better solution for positioning an image according to a variable from a Bean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;img src=&quot;icon.png&quot; style=&quot;position: absolute; top: 10px; left: #{page_bean.dbtable_variable}px;&quot;/&gt;" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ish. But I still get that error: #{} not allowed in a template text body.